# Incorrect length causing int not iterable error

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix

I am attempting to loop through a matrix, called `lattice`, randomly using the `randrange` function. My matrix is an 8x8 and prints fine.  However when I attempt to randomly loop through each element of this matrix I am getting the error

> 'TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable'

Due the upper limit of the range, `len(mymatrix)`. I'm unsure as to why this is.

```
   for R1 in randrange(0, (len(lattice)):
        for R2 in randrange(0, len(lattice)):
            H = -j*lattice[R1,R2]*(lattice[R1+1,R2],lattice[R1-1,R2], lattice[R1,R2+1],lattice[R1,R2-1]) +h*lattice[R1,R2]
            H_flip = -j*-1*mymatrix[R1,R2]*(lattice[R1+1,R2],lattice[R1-1,R2], lattice[R1,R2+1],lattice[R1,R2-1]) +h*lattice[R1,R2]
    print lattice[R1,R2]
```

I have not used `randrange` in a loop before, is it perhaps that it can't be used the same way range is used? I've also tried to set the range as:

```
for R1 in randrange(0, len(lattice)-1)
```

I thought maybe the length was one too long but to no avail.

Comment: Please post the some more details of your code as well as the the full error.

Comment: Just read the docs what `random.randrange` returns and compare it to what `range` returns.

Comment: Why are you trying to loop *randomly*?

Answer (score 0):

The method `randrange` does not return a range, but a randomly selected **element** instead as can be read in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange).

> `random.randrange(start, stop[, step])`
>
> Return a randomly selected element from `range(start, stop, step)`. This is equivalent to `choice(range(start, stop, step))`, but doesn’t actually build a range object.

That is why you get a `TypeError`, you are indeed trying to loop over an `int`.

I would not recommend looping in a random order over your lists, but if it turns out to be necessary, I would use `shuffle`.

```
from random import shuffle

# shuffle mutates your list so we need to do the following
rows, cols = range(len(lattice)), range(len(lattice))
shuffle(rows)
shuffle(cols)

for R1 in rows:
        for R2 in cols:
            # ...
```

Note that in Python3, you would need to cast your `range` to a `list` first.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. `randrange()` returns a single element from within the given range. On the other hand, `range()` returns a list of elements, and is therefore iterable.

You could try something like this:

```
stop = randrange(0, len(lattice)-1)
start = randrange(0, stop)
for R1 in randrange(start, stop):
     for...
```